# How can hours, minutes, and seconds be extracted from a time_point in milliseconds?

Tags: c++, date, c++11, c++-chrono

How can I extract hours, minutes, and seconds from a given `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::milliseconds>`?

My code in below does not return the hour correctly. It returns a vary large value for the hour (e.g., Hours: 472057, Minutes: 3).

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

auto hours = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(tp.time_since_epoch()).count();
auto minutes = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(tp.time_since_epoch()).count() % 60;

// Print the hours and minutes
std::cout << "Hours: " << hours << std::endl;
std::cout << "Minutes: " << minutes << std::endl;
```

Comment: You've skipped the part where you subtract off the "days" part.  This action separates the date/time into a date and time.  Then you can work on the time as you show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've specified C++11, and removed the part about using [Howard Hinnant's date lib](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), you'll have to re-create that part of the date lib that exists only as 3rd party lib until C++20.  This isn't too much trouble if you are content with UTC.  Getting local time is more effort:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    // This is a date_time in UTC
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    // This is a date in UTC
    auto tp_days = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400>>>(tp);

    // This is a time in UTC
    auto tod = tp - tp_days;

    // This is how to separate a duration into {h, m, s}
    auto h = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(tod);
    tod -= h;
    auto m = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(tod);
    tod -= m;
    auto s = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(tod);

    std::cout << "Hours: " << h.count() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Minutes: " << m.count() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Seconds: " << s.count() << '\n';
}
```

Note that this only works correctly for `system_clock` `time_point`s after 1970-01-01T00:00:00 UTC.  This is because `time_point_cast` truncates towards zero.  C++17 introduces `floor` which truncates towards negative infinity, and should be preferred as it works both before and after the epoch.

To get local time you'll need to figure out your current UTC offset and add that to your `time_point` prior to splitting it up into a date and time (prior to truncating to days precision).